# How to ssh to a computer using a ddns server

Tags: port-forwarding, dynamic-dns

I have Duck DNS installed on my linux machine and I want to be able to ssh to it remotely. The thing is I don't understand the port forwarding step. To complicate things, I live in a large house and my desktop goes through two routers to get to the WAN. I have the main router set up to port forward to the second router. But what I don't understand is what ip address I'm supposed to set the the second router to port forward to. Since my desktop doesn't have a static ip, how do I tell the router to look up my ip from DuckDNS?

Answer (score 0):

I would set up a DHCP reservation for that machine. This means that the machine does not have a true static IP (so, there's no problem picking it up and taking it somewhere else), but will always be allocated the same IP when on your home LAN.

DHCP reservation is a feature of your DHCP server, which is probably your router since you didn't say otherwise. Most routers have a fairly simple web form for setting up reservations.

Once the LAN IP is predicable then you can forward the port with confidence.